# Apache httpd 2.4.34 couldn't receive signal SIGTERM on SuSE 15

Tags: apache, opensuse, sigkill, sigterm, sles

I have install `apache httpd 2.4.34` on `SLES 15`, and there are six `httpd` processes running.

When I send signal `SIGTERM` to `httpd` process, all the six `httpd` process couldn't receive signal `SIGTERM` (I had `gdb` attched `httpd` process to catch signal `SIGTERM`),
but I find `kill 15 11143` return 0 via command strace. But httpd could reiveive signal `SIGKILL`, it's very strange.

And `apache httpd 2.4.34` running on other platform(`SLES12, SLES11, RHEL7`) could reiveive and handle signal `SIGTERM` normally.

**Does anyone encounter this phenomenon**?

```
+++
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="15"
VERSION_ID="15"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15"
ID="sles"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:15"

#uname -a
Linux linux-iv0h 4.12.14-23-default #1 SMP Tue May 29 21:04:44 UTC 2018 (cd0437b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#ps aux|grep httpd
root     11143  0.0  0.6  23612  6380 ?        Ss   04:33   0:00 ./httpd
nobody   11144  0.0  0.3  23612  3248 ?        S    04:33   0:00 ./httpd
nobody   11145  0.0  0.3  23612  3248 ?        S    04:33   0:00 ./httpd
nobody   11146  0.0  0.3  23612  3248 ?        S    04:33   0:00 ./httpd
nobody   11147  0.0  0.3  23612  3248 ?        S    04:33   0:00 ./httpd
nobody   11148  0.0  0.3  23612  3248 ?        S    04:33   0:00 ./httpd
+++
```